# How to serialize/deserialize java object to/from javax.JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization

Since Java 7 there has been a JSON standard.

Is there a simple or standard solution for serializing Java objects to JSON and back again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: thanks, I know about this thread. But I'm looking for a solution for the json library, that is included in java 7

Comment: You can use GSON [https://github.com/google/gson]. Using this library you can convert Json to Java object and vise versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). It's very simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jaxb annotations.